# animating div background with use of jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Ok, so I am trying to animated a DIV elements background-image with use of jQuery the background is a cloud which I would like to loop over and over in a slow like moving pattern. Any idea how I can do this?

I tried this code but no luck so not sure whats wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
    $.fn.extend({
    animateHeader: function(){
       $(this).find('#header').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
       $(this).find('#header').animate({
            backgroundPosition: '-20px 0px'
       }, 100, 'linear', function() {
            animateHeader(self);
       });
    }
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).animateHeader();
    });

    });
```

P.S. The background image it self is 1598 x 337px here is the way it looks if some one is interested: http://i54.tinypic.com/25zng2r.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't by default, but you can use this plugin to achieve your desired result:
http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/

Comment: huh so no way to animate it otherwise with jQuery, odd I though jQuery had similar effect/animation library as Dojo's

Comment: Nope but the JQuery team is always taking successful plugins into consideration for implementation into the core. JQuery's still a baby - I'm sure it'll be in there soon enough :)

Comment: huh, well Dojo or Mootools are much easier to work with well i will go back to Mootools since animating background is drilled into Mootools core, without need for any plug-ins, bit sad about jQuery truth